# the django slug can't contain a "love" speech?

Tags: django, slug, satchmo

I use django-1.1 and satchmo (commit: 1385  75a2ea838067)

I found that if there is a "love" speech in the slug item, for example, love-x10, dsfdsfloveddd, love-love ...
the product's url is "http://example.com/product/lovelove/", if you click "add to cart" button, the server give me a Blank Page, Empty! And the server is temporarily unable to provide services.
What a strange situation. If you do not believe that you can personally try to it.

Comment: I have an 1.2 beta and it works fine, I've just tried :) I think you should search your code for bugs or do a step by step debugging. Are you working on windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with problems lke this is [opening a ticket](http://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/issues/?status=new&status=open) for the Satchmo project.

I looked through open ticket list and found a few that could be related to the behavior you're seeing but nothing that matches it completely.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an url blocked by a dummy firewall.

Much less probable is a bad configurad server that dies after error without any message and also other very obscure error.

Clarification: The string "love" has been never part of Satchmo. I have never seen a blank page on a correctly configured Django server in the case of any error. It displays at least some template or a general error message or at least error message from web server in the case of Django timeout.